# Can I use floating point numbers inside div IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of `div`s on pages, some `div`s have IDs like `word_float_number` (example `group_3.0` or `group_4.0` , others just have word IDs). When I try to select these `div`s with jQuery, none of them are selected, like it cannot find them. Can I use number inside `div` IDs? I need to cluster elements by those floating point numbers on a page.

Comment: can you provide your markup and jQuery parts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `.` character. You need to escape (with `\.` in the JQuery selector) or remove it from the ids, because JQuery will intepret it as a css class devider.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can use numbers in jQuery selectors, however as @nfechner says, you need to escape any `.` (dot) characters with a backslash due to it being a class selector and jQuery seeing it that way.

Using the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)  selector (`[name^="value"]`), you could select all `word_[float]` elements using this:

```
$('div[id^="word_"]')
```

Which will select any `div` with an `id` attribute starting with `word_`. You'd do the same with `group_` like this:

```
$('div[id^="group_"]')
```

And so on.